# Find a single row and update it with nested queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, subquery

Good evening everyone, I'm trying to do an update on a Table but I can't really make it work
The feature needed is:
-Watch a field on a form, it contains the number of people that need to sit at the restaurant table.
-Find the first free table that has enough seats, set it as busy and assign a random waiter

Any idea?

more db infos:
**Table** "Waiters" is composed by ID(Autonumber),Name(Short Text). Has 2 names atm
**Table** "Tables" is composed by ID(Autonumber),Seats(Number),Busy(y/n),Waiter(short text). All tables have a fixed number of seats and have no Waiter + not busy

**SOLUTION:**

In the end i used "First" for the assignment and it works perfectly as it follows:

```
UPDATE Tables SET Tables.Waiter = DLookUp("FirstName","TopWtr")
WHERE ID IN (SELECT FIRST (ID)
FROM Tables
WHERE Seats >= Val(Forms!Room!Text12) AND Waiter Is Null);
```

Top wasn't working because it was returning multiple records - every table with same number of seats - and couldn't make it work with DISTINCT. This works probably because the table is already ordered by seats

Thanks to June7 for the input

Comment: please post tables and data, for example you have Camerieri.id an nobody can guess where you get them from

Comment: Also, how can ID be IN field Busy? Isn't Busy a Yes/No type? Again, why look for ID IN Seats?

Comment: Should avoid using reserved words as object names. **Name** is a reserved word.

Comment: Nothing you show prevents assigning the same waiter to all tables. Strictly random assignment could mean disproportionate tasking. Need rules.

Comment: Exactly what purpose does the Busy field serve? Seems if table has a waiter assigned, that would indicate table is busy and therefore Busy field is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot SET a field value to result of a SELECT subquery - SELECT returns a dataset not a single value. Can return a single value with domain aggregate function.

Build a query object named TopWtr:
`SELECT Top 1 ID FROM Waiters ORDER BY Rnd(ID);`

Then use DLookup to pull that value. The Busy field seems redundant because if table has a waiter assigned that would indicate busy.

```
UPDATE Tables SET Tables.Waiter = DLookUp("ID","TopWtr"), Tables.Busy = True 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Tables 
             WHERE Seats >= Val(Forms!Room!Testo17) AND Waiter Is Null 
             ORDER BY Seats)
```

An INNER JOIN may be preferable to WHERE clause:

```
UPDATE Tables INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Tables 
             WHERE Seats >= Val(Forms!Room!Testo17) AND Waiter Is Null 
             ORDER BY Seats) AS T1
ON Tables.ID = T1.ID
SET Tables.Waiter = DLookUp("ID","TopWtr"), Tables.Busy = True
```

Comment: Ok seems better now, but it only works once and only with a particular number, can't understand why. I have 6 tables with 4 seats, 2 with 6 seats, 2 with 8 seats. It works only if i put a number between 0 and 4 (number of seats of the first table), and only for the first assignment. If i put another number it says "update 0 rows", if i put again 0-4 same thing. Seems like it can see only the first table

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I tried both of them but they don't work. They both say "can't find ID" twice. I'm updating main post with a full view of the actual DB so maybe it's more clear if i've done errors before this

Comment: I tried creating a query that does just SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Tables 
             WHERE Seats >= Val(Forms!Room!Testo17) AND Waiter Is Null 
             ORDER BY Seats to see what happens. If i set 2 people it gives me random result. 1: doesn't give me the TOP 1 but many more. 2: If i set 8 seats it gives me the tables with 8 seats. If i set 3 it gives me only the tables with 4 seats. I think there is something wrong in another place.

Comment: All I can say is this works for me. Should post data as text tables, not images.

Comment: The tables are as i edited in the main post. If i just run the query to select me the top 1, it selects me more than 1 and maybe not all of the eligible. This works for you? The tables are really simple.. i can't understand what can be wrong. Tables 1-6 have 4 seats, 7-8 have 6 seats, 9-10 have 8 seats. All not busy and without Waiter. Text17 is just an unbound text field with format "general number"